# How can I remove assign characters at near the end of a string in php?

Tags: php

```
$text_one = "Blue - Art-1011-No.1 [Pinpoint Light Blue]-78" ;
```

I want to remove character " - " show in the near the end of string

```
$regex = "/[.*?!@#$&-_ ]+$/";
$result = preg_replace($regex, "", $text_one);

$result =  Blue - Art-1011-No.1 [Pinpoint Light Blue
```

what is the wrong? while i want to

```
$result = Blue - Art-1011-No.1 [Pinpoint Light Blue]
```

p/s: i dont want using possition because other string maybe -878, -999, -1234

Comment: SO is not a coding service. What have **you** tried and researched before posting on SO?

Comment: Yes i was try it before - but i am not good with preg_match function

Comment: `$regex = "/\-[^-]+$/";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$string = "Blue - Art-1011-No.1 [Pinpoint Light Blue]-78";
$needle = "-";
echo substr( $string, 0, strrpos( $string, $needle, 0 ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP [strrpos()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php) function :

```
$text_one = "Blue - Art-1011-No.1 [Pinpoint Light Blue]-78" ; 
$needle = "-";
$result =  substr( $text_one, 0, strrpos( $text_one, $needle, 0 ) );
echo $result;
```

Comment: Wow - you are great. Thanks so much :) save my life